# How to take selected-area screenshot to clipboard once it's selected?

Tags: screenshots, copy-paste

How to take a selected-area screenshot, so that it's copied to the clipboard automatically once it's selected? (exactly like [`Win+Shift+S`](https://www.askvg.com/tip-use-winshifts-hotkey-to-take-selected-area-screenshot-in-windows-10/) on Windows, but I need it for Android)

This will enable me to quickly —*saving tremendous time & pain (when I need to reuse this a lot)*— paste it within any note-taking application (like [Squid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.steadfastinnovation.android.projectpapyrus)).

**Motive**

I use *Squid* a lot in split-screen-view with a book reader app (like [ezPDF](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader)) and many times, I need to take selected-area-screenshot of a part from a book to drop it in my note paper in Squid where I'm taking notes.

One way to do this is to use Samsung's [Smart Select](http://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/what-is/smart-select/), then share the selected-area screenshot to Squid. This unfortunately forces opening Squid in full screen (which destroys the split-screen view, so I need to waste time again to set the split-screen view of the two apps). Also, in Squid, it forces creating a new separate useless note (not the one I'm working with, so I need to waste time again re-navigating to my original note after copying my captured selected-area screenshot to the clipboard and then deleting the useless note). This wastes a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Samsung select copy-paste, use the inbuilt options from ezPDF.

From the floating 3 dot menu at the right centre → Menus → Edit → snapshot → select the area and take snapshot → share with → Squid (choose always since you do that frequently).

The picture gets posted in Squid without switching apps. Here's an example of both apps in split screen mode with the transfer of a screenshot.

[image]

Comment: We're you able to test it out?

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods that may help to solve this problem. The first perfect solution is using "Gboard" (Google Keyboard) which can copy the selected-area screenshot to the clipboard immediately. The second need to use the "copy to clipboard" app to "share" the screenshot to the clipboard and thus can not automatically copy the screenshot to the clipboard.

---

### Gboard - Automatically copy to clipboard

Try Gboard (the Google Keyboard) as the [page](https://techviral.net/save-recent-screenshots-to-gboard-clipboard/#:%7E:text=How%20to%20Save%20Recent%20Screenshots%20to%20Gboard%20Clipboard,and%20images%20in%20the%20suggestion%20bar%20option.%20%E6%9B%B4%E5%A4%9A%E9%A1%B9%E7%9B%AE) say. Enabling the "Save recent screenshots in clipboard" option may help.

1. In Gboard's settings, click "Clipboard" as the following.

   [image]
2. Enable the "Save recent screenshots in clipboard" option.

   [image]

---

### Copy to Clipboard - share to clipboard

I've tried the above method but I didn't have the option "Save recent screenshots in clipboard" in Gboard's Clipboard settings. So the following is the second method I figured out.

Using [Copy to Clipboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slash.clipboard).

[image]

After capturing the screen, my Android device will prompt me whether to edit the screenshot (like cutting and painting) or share to other devices or other apps. Therefore, after installing the "Copy to Clipboard" app, the "Copy to Clipboard" app icon will appear on the "Share to other apps" prompt as the following.

[image]

Click the "Copy to Clipboard" icon and the screenshot will be copied to the clipboard. This uses the same mechanism when you copy an image in the browser on your Android device.

The advantage of "Copy to Clipboard" over "Gboard" is that you can edit or cut the screenshot before copying it to the clipboard and the image will also be saved to the photo album.

Hopefully, these two methods can help.

Answer (score 0):

As [Qingwei Li's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/250904/44325) mentioned, you can download Screenshot Master and copy it to the clipboard. Just make a screenshot with Screenshot Master and share it to the clipboard.

The Nebo app can get the picture from the clipboard with the default paste.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).